# setInverval not working with jQuery attr select

Tags: jquery, setinterval

If I log data to the console this code is working fine, but for some reason the jQuery selector won't work, although it does work when it's not in the setInterval.

```
    var refreshId = setInterval(function() {
        if ($('body').width()<=979) {
            console.log('small');
            $('.switch-type').attr('data-type', 'vertical');
        } else {
            $('.switch-type').attr('data-type', 'horizonal');
            console.log('big');
        }
    }, 1000);
```

**Update:**

Code works fine, it's just that jQuery mobile has already done it's think by the time this executes.

Comment: You'll need to post the markup (HTML) if you need help with selectors.

Comment: Also, how do you know it's not working?

Comment: make sure you've got that in a `$(document).ready(function() { ... })`

Comment: It works fine here: http://jsfiddle.net/9r2h3/

Comment: It looks to be working fine here: http://jsfiddle.net/arunpjohny/YPd9p/ . You can resize the result panel to see the color of the `Type` text changing.

Comment: Okay, you guys tipped me off, I'm using jQuery mobile and trying to switch the display of radios from vertical to horizontal, but the code has already executed by the time this runs.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can try to log to the console

```
console.log($('.switch-type'));
```

In that way you know if the DOM element exists when you are trying to access it. I recently had a problem like this, then I realized that the element wasn't in the DOM when I was trying to use it.